# forward jump using third person controller unity

Tags: unity-game-engine

How do you forward jump using the third person controller in the standard asset of unity, i tried it , it did forward jump however it is now double jumping.

```c#
void HandleGroundedMovement(bool crouch, bool jump)
{
    // check whether conditions are right to allow a jump:
    if (jump && !crouch && m_Animator.GetCurrentAnimatorStateInfo(0).IsName("Grounded"))
    {
        //velocity x is multiplied by 2f<--I add this
        //
        // jump!
        m_Rigidbody.velocity = new Vector3(m_Rigidbody.velocity.x*2f, m_JumpPower, m_Rigidbody.velocity.z);

        m_IsGrounded = false;
        m_Animator.applyRootMotion = false;
        m_GroundCheckDistance = 0.1f;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your IF statement is only checking for inputs and whether or not the animator is grounded. You have a variable named "m_IsGrounded" which you could use instead. That should stop the double jump.